# getsockopt(...,SO_ORIGINAL_DST,...) occasionally returns client address

Tags: c++, linux, getsockopt

I am working on a project that accepts HTTP requests and forwards them onto a destination. We use Linux (2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64) and TPROXY.  I'll put in the details below.

The problem I am seeing is that OCCASIONALLY (1 time out of a 1000 sometimes 1 time out of a million), Linux is returning the peer address as the destination address.

Has anyone seen this occur?  I saw one note on the web from 2007 so I think that might be a little dated.

I have the following code (pardon the inconsistent methodology displayed here):

```
struct sockaddr clientaddr;
socklen_t clientlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
int status = getpeername(acceptedSocket, &clientaddr, &clientlen);

char clientName[256];
clientName[0] = '\0';
int clientport = 0;
if (status == 0) {
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, (void *) &((struct sockaddr_in *)&clientaddr)->sin_addr, clientName, 256);
    clientport = ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in *)& clientaddr)->sin_port);
    **printf("Socket::acceptConnection: getpeername :  %s:%d\n", clientName, clientport); fflush(stdout);**
}
else
{
    LOGINFO(WARNING(352), "Socket::acceptConnection: Could not get client from accepted socket.\n");
}

status = getsockopt(acceptedSocket, SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST, (struct sockaddr *) &destaddr, &destlen);

if (status == 0) {
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, (void *) &destaddr.sin_addr, destinationName, 256);
    int portnumber = ntohs(destaddr.sin_port);
    ssize_t dl = strlen(destinationName);
    sprintf(&destinationName[dl], ":%d", portnumber);
    **printf("Socket::acceptConnection: getsockopt :  %s\n", destinationName); fflush(stdout);**
}
else
{
    LOGINFO(WARNING(352), "Socket::acceptConnection: Could not get destination from accepted socket.\n");
}
```

What happens is that *most* of the time the getpeername and getsockopt report correctly (see the IPTABLE config below).

Unfortunately *occasionally* get getsockopt report is the same as getpeername, i.e., the destination is the same as the peer.

IPTABLE Config:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT 
-A PREROUTING -s 10.2.0.203/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY --on-port 8080 --on-ip 10.2.0.204 --tproxy-mark 0x1/0xffffffff 
-A DIVERT -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff 
-A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
```

We have logged the activity and it looks OK.  For example, we get the following output:

```
Socket::acceptConnection: getpeername :  10.2.0.203:48517
Socket::acceptConnection: getsockopt :  10.2.0.203:48517
```

Yet the log from IPTables shows the IP addresses as being correct:

```
Jul  9 17:37:06 2U-204 kernel: [258876.105481] IN=eth3 OUT= MAC=00:1b:21:61:03:99:00:1b:21:61:c0:70:08:00 **SRC=10.2.0.203 DST=192.168.200.206** LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=56054 DF PROTO=TCP **SPT=48517 DPT=80** WINDOW=17896 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Jul  9 17:37:06 2U-204 kernel: [258876.105697] IN=eth3 OUT= MAC=00:1b:21:61:03:99:00:1b:21:61:c0:70:08:00 **SRC=10.2.0.203 DST=192.168.200.206** LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=56055 DF PROTO=TCP **SPT=48517 DPT=80** WINDOW=35 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

I'm really stumped on this.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `getsockopt( ... SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST ... )`? AFAIK `SO_ORIGINAL_DST` is intended to be used with the NAT `REDIRECT` target not `TPROXY`.

Try a simple `getsockname()` instead.